# Does strict convexity imply differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that convexity does not imply differentiability, for example f(x)=|x| is convex but not differentiable. However, |x| is not strictly convex. So I wonder whether strict convexity imply differentiability.

I did some search and found out the Wikipedia implicitly gives the negative answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions
It says that "a strongly convex function is also strictly convex" and "a function doesn't have to be differentiable in order to be strongly convex".

Can anyone provide a concrete example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35):

$$f(x)=x^2+|x|$$ is strictly convex because of the $x^2$ term but not differentiable at $0$ because of the $|x|$ term

Answer (score 23):

Choose a strictly convex function $u$ and some sequences $(x_n)$ and $(a_n)$ such that every $a_n$ is positive and the series $\sum\limits_na_n(1+|x_n|)$ converges. Then the formula
$$
v(x)=\sum\limits_na_n|x-x_n|
$$
defines a proper function $v$ such that $u+v$ is strictly convex, and not differentiable at any $x_n$.

The countable set of points $X=\{x_n\}$ may be dense. The function $v$ is differentiable at every $x$ not in $X$, with
$$
v'(x)=\sum\limits_na_n\,\mathrm{sgn}(x-x_n).
$$

Comment: This might actually be already the most general case: I don't think it's possible for a function to be strictly convex and non-differentiable on _more than a null set_.

Comment: @left, that is interesting. Would you have a reference? (But null sets may be uncountable.)

Comment: I'm not sure about it, I only vaguely remember some argument with Sobolev spaces. But you're right, as null sets can be uncountable it doesn't proove your example is the most general one.

Comment: @Didier Piau: Every convex function $f:I \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$, where $I$ is an open interval, is finitely differentiable at co-countably many points in $I.$ In fact, the following stronger result holds: both unilateral derivatives exist finitely at each point in $I.$ Moreover, this result is sharp in the sense that every countable subset of $\mathbb R$ can be the set of non-differentiability for a convex function. Also, the 2nd derivative of a convex function exists (finitely) almost everywhere (Lebesgue measure). For more, see http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/ab1cdc66df05b84d

Comment: @Dave, thanks a lot. I should have seen the co-countability myself, this is the old argument that any summable family of nonnegative real numbers contains at most countably many positive elements. The fact that every co-countable subset of $\mathbb R$ can be the set of non-differentiability stems from the example in my post, I think. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @Did So you've proved that the set of non-diffrentiable points of a convex function can be at most countable and may well be dense. Is it only true for $\Bbb R$ or we can generalize it for general ${\Bbb R}^n$ or other metric spaces ?

Comment: Rademacher's theorem says that every locally Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable at least in a set of full measure. Since convex functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are locally Lipschitz continuous, all convex functions are differentiable in a set of full measure. That type of analysis comes from Clarke's sense of differentiable function, see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Clarke_generalized_derivative

Answer (score 13):

The function
$$f(x)=\max(e^x,e^{-x})$$
is strictly convex but not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: The maximum of two strictly convex functions is strictly convex, so taking any two such functions whose graphs intersect at a point where the slopes differ should work as well.

Comment: Also your $f$ can be seen as $f(x)=\max(e^x,e^{-x})=e^{\max(x,-x)}=e^{|x|}$.