# An inequality for divided differences of an increasing concave function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Take $0<a<b<c<d$ and consider $f$ strictly increasing and strictly concave (with $f(0)\geq 0$). I would like to prove that $$\frac{f(d)-f(b)}{f(c)-f(a)}<\frac{d-b}{c-a}$$ without any further assumption on $a,b,c,d$. Is it possible? Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes, this is true. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/946392).

Comment: Sorry Mice Elf, what is the 3-points convexity definition?

Comment: $f(ta+(1-t)b)\le tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The increasing assumption allows you to rearrange the desired inequality as 
$$\frac{f(d)-f(b)}{d-b}<\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}, \quad a<b<c<d \tag{1}$$
First, prove (1) with $b=c$, that is 
$$\frac{f(d)-f(b)}{d-b}<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}, \quad a<b<d \tag{2}$$
This only requires writing out the strict concavity property $f(ta+(1-t)d)> tf(a)+(1-t)f(d)$ with a suitable $t$. (Such that $ta+(1-t)d = b$)

Once you have (2), proceed by  applying it twice as follows:
$$\frac{f(d)-f(b)}{d-b}<\frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}<\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}$$

Comment: Great! Many thanks!