# Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function . What can be said about the set of points where $f$ is not differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, descriptive-set-theory

Hope this isn't a duplicate.

Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function. Let $D(f) = \{x \in \Bbb R : f$ is discontinuous at $x\} $ and $N(f) = \{x \in \Bbb R : f $ is not differentiable at $x \}$ .

It is easy to prove that $D(f)$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set i.e. can be expressed as a (at most) Countable union of closed sets (possibly empty). Now considering $N(f)$ , since by definition, $D(f) \subseteq N(f) $ , it follows that **$N(f)$ contains an at most Countable union of closed sets(possibly empty).** In case we further assume that [$f$ is convex , it can be proved that $N(f)$ is at most countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946311/a-convex-function-is-differentiable-at-all-but-countably-many-points?rq=1)

But my question is **what can be said about the structure of $N(f)$ when $f$ is considered in full generality i.e. all we are assuming is that  $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a function and no other added restriction is posed on $f$** .

Comment: You need to study Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Saks_theorem

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I've studied a version of Denjoy's theorem that tells if a function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ has one-sided derivatives on $\Bbb R$ \ $A$ where A is a countable subset of $\Bbb R$, then $f$ has derivatives on $\Bbb R$ with at most countably many exceptions. But  that does not address my problem here. In the theorem, you are taking assumptions on one-sided derivatives, but I'm not assuming anything except that $f$ is a $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ function !