# smooth envelope of the convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We know that every convex function $g:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ is locally Lipschitz, and therefore $g$ is differentiable almost everywhere (Alexandrov's theorem says that $g$ is in fact twice differentiable almost everywhere and so $g$ is ${\rm C}^1$ almost everywhere). For $n=1,2$ we define the lower (upper, resp.) smooth convex envelope of $g$ as follows:

$L_n(g):={\rm sup}\{h:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}: h\leq g,\; h\;\hbox{is convex},\;h\in{\rm C}^n(\mathbf{R})\}$

($U_n(g):={\rm inf}\{h:\mathbf{R}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}: h\geq g,\; h\;\hbox{is convex},\;h\in{\rm C}^n(\mathbf{R})\}$, resp.).

My question is: can we formulate necessary and/or sufficient conditions on $g$ which yield the following conclusions:

(1) $L_1(g)$ exists ($U_1(g)$ exists, resp.), meaning that there exists at least one lower (upper, resp.) function ${\rm C}^1$-smooth function $h$,

(2) $L_1(g)=g$ ($U_1(g)=g$, resp.),

(3) $L_2(g)$ exists ($U_2(g)$ exists, resp.),  meaning that there exists at least one lower (upper, resp.) function ${\rm C}^2$-smooth function $h$,

(4) $L_2(g)=g$ ($U_2(g)=g$, resp.).

Ofcourse, we can extend the question to the case $h\in{\rm C}^n(\mathbf{R})$ for every $n\in\mathbf{N}$, or even to the case when $h$ is analytic functon on $\mathbf{R}$, but for my purposes it is enough to consider the case $n=1$ and $n=2$. If classical smoothness can not be considered, I would settle for weakly differentiable functions $h\in {\rm W}^{2,p}_{loc}(\mathbf{R})$ for some $p\geq 1$, but I have the feeling that this could be much harder question. One possibility of extra assumption on $g$ is, for instance, that $g$ is differentiable (or twice differenntiable) except on at most countable points $x\in\mathbf{R}$. Remark. Corollary 7.2.4 in Garling: A Course in Mathematical Analysis, Volume 1, provides that one-sided derivatives of convex function $g$, denoted by $g'(x-)$ and $g'(x+)$, exist everwhere, except on at most countably many points $x\in\mathbf{R}$. Here

[A convex function is differentiable at all but countably many points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/946311/a-convex-function-is-differentiable-at-all-but-countably-many-points)

we have an improvement of the corollary from Garling's book, which says that every convex function is differentiable except at most countably many points, but the question still stands.

Comment: [This](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-322-02/S0002-9947-1990-0986024-2/) paper might be relevant for the $\mathcal{C}^1$ case. It is also noteworthy that requiring the convex envelope to be in $\mathcal{C}^2$ is a fairly strong; there are simple examples of smooth functions that do not have a $\mathcal{C}^2$ envelope.

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to the paper by Griewank and Rabier. If ${\rm C}^2$-envelope is to strong, I guess we are left with ${\rm W}^{2,p}$-envelope, but I have no idea how to build such Sobolev functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer:

Always $L_1 (g) = L_2 (g) = g$, Think about  the set of all affine functions majorized by $g$

Also the way  you defined functions $L_i (g) ,$ and $U_i (g)$ doesn't make any sense! I am assuming you meant  for all $x \in R$ 
$$L_n(g)(x) :={\rm sup}\{h(x): \quad h\leq g,\; h\;\hbox{is convex},\;h\in{\rm C}^n(\mathbf{R})\}$$

$$U_n(g)(x) :={\rm inf}\{h(x): \quad h\ge g,\; h\;\hbox{is convex},\;h\in{\rm C}^n(\mathbf{R})\}$$

Note that since $g$ is convex on all over $\Bbb R$ then $g = g^{**}$ where

$$ g(x) = g^{**} (x) =  \sup \{\langle x , y \rangle\ - g^{*}(y) : \quad y \in R\} $$

Which clearly says $g$ is the pointwise supremum of some affine functions.

Comment: Well, if there exists (at least one) affine functiion $h$ such that $h\leq g$, it makes sense to try to prove that $L_1(g)=L_2(g)=g$. Otherwise, I don't see the argument. I think that one possibility for additional condition on $g$ is $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}g(x)=+\infty$. Then, by strict convexity of $g$, it follows $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}|{{g(x)}\over{x}}|>0$, and there exists at least one lower affine bound, so it probably gives $L_1(g)=L_2(g)=g$, but I am not sure. Maybe you can be more explicit in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: For sure there exist at least one affine function . Do you know what subdifferential means ?  At  every point on $g$ has at least one subgradient @Andrija

Comment: I see, we always have an affine lower bound. There was a typo in the definition of $U_i(g)$ (sup instead of inf), I corrected it. I guess this means that every convex function is supremum of piecewise affine and continuous lower bounds. From there, we can probably prove that $L_1(g)=L_2(g)=g$. Thanks...