# Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be convex. Is the set of non-differentiability points countable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be convex and
$$
F := \{x \in \mathbb R^d \mid f \text{ is not Fréchet differentiable at }x\}.
$$

If $d=1$, then $F$ is countable. [The proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/946392/368425) in this case relies on the order of $\mathbb R$.

Is $F$ still countable if $d>1$?

Comment: If $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is convex and you define $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ by $f(x,y)=g(x)$ then $f$ is convex...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I could not get your idea. Did you meant to reduce the multi-dimensional case to1D? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y) = |x|$ is convex, but is non-differentiable on the uncountable line $\{(x,y) : x=0\}$.

Comment: Thank you @GEdgar so much. I have posted your example as an answer to remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DavidC.Ullrich pointed in his comment, the result does not generalize to higher dimension. @GEdgar  provided below example
$$
f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, (x,y) \mapsto |x|.
$$

Then $f$ is not Fréchet differentiable on the set $\{(x,y) : x=0\}$ which is uncountable.