# Does strict convexity imply continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

Let $E$ be a normed space and $f:E \to \mathbb R$ convex.

- If $E = \mathbb R^d$ then $f$ is locally Lipschitz-continuous.
- If $E$ is infinite-dimensional then $f$ is not necessarily continuous. There exists [discontinuous linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional) on an infinite-dimensional normed space.

Now we assume more that $f$ is strictly convex, i.e.,
$$
f(tx + (1-t)y) < tf(x)+(1-t)f(y) \quad \forall t \in (0, 1), \forall x,y\in E \text{ s.t. } x\neq y.
$$

- Strict convexity [does not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67853/does-strict-convexity-imply-differentiability) imply differentiability.

> Does strict convexity of $f$ imply that $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Just add any continuous, strictly convex function (e.g. the norm squared) to a discontinuous linear functional. The sum of a convex $f$ and strictly convex $g$ must be strictly convex, as
\begin{align*}
(f + g)(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) &= f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) + g(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) \\
&\le \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y) + g(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) \\
&< \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y) + \lambda g(x) + (1 - \lambda)g(y) \\
&= \lambda (f + g)(x) + (1 - \lambda)(f + g)(y)
\end{align*}
for distinct $x, y \in E$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1)$. Also, if $f + g$ were continuous at any point, then so would be $f = (f + g) - g$, by the algebra of continuous functions.