# For a Wiener process, when can one exchange “for all $t$” and “almost surely”?

Tags: derivatives, brownian-motion, quantifiers, almost-everywhere, wiener-measure

Certain local properties of the [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) $W_t$ are quick to prove at $t = 0$, for instance:

1. almost surely $W_t$ is monotonous on no interval beginning at $t = 0$;
2. almost surely $W_t$ is not right-differentiable at $t = 0$.

Then, because $W_{t_0+t} - W_t$ is a Wiener process, we can conclude that

1. for any $t \ge 0$, almost surely $W_t$ is monotonous on no interval beginning at $t$,
2. for any $t \ge 0$, almost surely $W_t$ is not right-differentiable at $t$.

Thus at any countable set of times, in particular a dense one, both hold almost surely.
Now, if the first holds at a certain $t = t_0$ then it holds for all $t$ in a nonempty open interval to the right of $t_0$, so almost surely it must hold for all $t$.
We have successfully exchanged “for all $t$” and “almost surely” for the first property.

For the second property we are less fortunate: [there are continuous functions not differentiable on a countable dense subset but differentiable on its complement.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/67857/791850)
Yet this “exchange of quantifiers” is still valid here: almost surely $W_t$ is nowhere differentiable. However the proofs I have seen are considerably more involved than that for only $t = 0$.

Hence my question: **is there a clean condition on the events $A_t$ under which
$$\inf_{t\ge0} \Pr(W \in A_t) = 1 \implies \Pr\Bigl( W \in \bigcap_{t\ge0} A_t \Bigr) = 1 \text?$$**
I am interested in “local” events $A_t$; let's suppose
$$A_t \in \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \sigma(\, W_{t+\delta} \colon 0 \le \delta < \varepsilon \,) \text, \quad \text{$t \ge 0$.}$$
An obvious starting point would be
$$A_t \subseteq \bigcup_{\varepsilon>0} \bigcap_{0\le\delta<\varepsilon} A_{t+\delta} \text,$$
as with the first property concerning monotonicity above.
It would be extra nice if the condition applied to the second property about differentiability.